# Extension of Borel map from a separable metric space to a Polish space

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, polish-spaces

Suppose that $f:X\to Y$ is a Borel map from separable metric space $X$ to a $T_3$ space $Y$.

Does there always exist a Polish space $\tilde X \supseteq X$ and $T_3$ space $\tilde Y\supseteq Y$ and an extension $\tilde f:\tilde X\to \tilde Y$ of $f$ in the sense that $\tilde f$ is Borel and $\tilde f(x) = f(x)$ for $x\in X$?

Context: I'm trying to consider spaces which are Borel images of separable metric spaces. However, the theory seems to be available for Polish spaces and not separable metric spaces. That's why I'm trying to show that a Borel image of separable metric space is a subspace of a Borel image of a Polish space, for which I know what to do. I've tried to do this by exhibiting a Borel map $g:\tilde X\to X$, however, thats only really available if $X$ is an analytic set. Thus I think this might be approachable by extending both the domain and codomain, hence the question.

Comment: What you are writing under context is slightly different. If $X$ is not a Borel subset of $\tilde{X}$, the image $f(X)$ need not be a Borel image. Actually, if $X$ is not measurably isomorphic to a Polish space, the canonical inclusion $i:X\to\tilde{X}$ will not have a Borel image.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker For $X$ to be a Borel image here means that there exists some surjective Borel map $f:T\to X$ where $T$ is separable metric space, in your example identity map $X\to X$ is a desired Borel map.

Comment: But $f(X)$ will generally still not be the image of a Polish space. Indeed, if $f$ is injective, there is no difference.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker you need to clarify what is the point that you're making. I'm not sure if there is some misunderstanding here, on my part or yours

Comment: Let $X$ be a separable metrizable space and $f:X\to X$ the identity. In general, there is no way to extend $X$ to a Polish space so that $f(X)$ is Borel or analytic.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yeah I agree, if you only extend the domain, then for this to be possible we need $X$ to be analytic in any Polish space that contains $X$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Don't get the context wrong though, I know I can't write everything as a Borel image of a Polish space, what I'm trying to explain in the context given is that if $Y$ is an image of a separable metric space by a Borel map, then I'm trying to extend $Y$ to a space $\tilde Y$ which is an image of a Polish space by a Borel map. This was the reason for the question in the first place, that its impossible to replace "separable metric" by "Polish". But there's still hope for it to be *subspace* of such image of Polish space.